# Have I done this database normalization question right?

Tags: database, data-science, data-analysis, database-normalization

I'm learning database normalization, got a question but don't know if I've done this correctly or not.

[image]

Here is my solution:
[image]

Comment: Normalization doesn't introduce new attributes. You introduced "Customer Firstname", "Customer Lastname", "Customer ID", "Item ID".

Comment: Show all steps of your work referencing & following your textbook until stuck then ask a specific question. Now you are just asking us to rewrite a textbook. Don't expect us to redo your homework when we could just check steps. See [ask] & hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. PS "With the following FDs" is not enough information. You mean those FDs form a cover. PS Use text, not images/links, for text, including tables & ERDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my knowledge your solution is not good

**My Solution**

Simply I change your data like this

[image]

Now I can see this relation is in 0th normal form

So remove name column and created new relation like below

[image]

Now customer relation is in

- 1st normal form because no multi-valued
- 2nd normal form because no partially dependencies
- 3rd normal form because contains only columns that are
  non-transitively dependent on the primary key

Shopper relation is like this, but it is in 0th normal form yet
[image]

Now I remove `purchased_item` column from shopper relation and create new relation as below
[image]

Now Purchased relation is in

- 1st normal form because no multi-valued
- 2nd normal form because no partially dependencies
- 3rd normal form because contains only columns that are
  non-transitively dependent

So now I update shopper relation like below
[image]

both `ID` and `Item_ID` are primary keys (Composite primary key)

Now customer, purchased and shopper relations are in 3rd normal form because no multi-valued attributes, all are fully dependent on primary key, no transitive attributes.

Final relations:

- Customer (**ID**, Name)
- Purchased_items (**Item_ID**,  Item_Name)
- Shopper (**Customer_ID, Item_ID**)

My bad, I forgot to specifically mention that **in normalization we can't add new attribute or drop attributes**. So in here I simply change your data relation into a more understandable relation only. Thank to @Mike Sherrill 'Cat Recall for pointing this issue.

Comment: Normalization doesn't introduce new attributes.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' thank you for pointing out this issue in my solution

Comment: Use text, not images/links, for text, including tables & ERDs.